# RecyclerView can't scroll up when embed under RelativeView and SwipeToRefresh

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have the below layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

It's basically having a `recyclerView` embedded in a `SwipeToRefresh`. This works well where I could scroll my recyclerView up and down. When reaching the top, and I pull down, the Refresh Happens.

Given I need to add an empty View dynamically, I have wrap the Empty View and `RecyclerView` under the `RelativeLayout`. This is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/my_empty_view"
            layout="@layout/fragment_empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

By adding this `RelativeLayout` between the `RecyclerView` and `SwipeToRefreshLayout`, the `RecyclerView` can only scroll down. It can not scroll up anymore, as whenever I try to scroll up, the `SwipeToRefresh` take place instead.

Why is this a problem? Is there any way to solve the problem while retaining my layout?

Thanks!

Comment: Apparently the issue is reported in https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=78191.

Answer (score 0):

A scrollable view must be embedded in a SwipeRefreshLayout immediately.So you can let the RelativeLayout be embedded in a ScrollView and the ScrollView is embedded in the SwipeRefreshLayout.

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 >
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/my_empty_view"
        layout="@layout/fragment_empty_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" />
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: To help better answer the question, make sure you include some code in addition to your textual solution.